# Configure ninject to work with azure

Tags: azure, ninject

I cant get Ninject to start in a Azure application. If i set the mvc3 project as startup project, everything works fine, but if i use the cloud project, ninject does not load. Do i need to set it to start somewhere?

as you might imagine, i am totally new to azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting specific errors? We use Ninject in Azure just fine.  Just had to make sure that .DLL's were deployed with the application

Comment: no errors, but the app_start file that comes with Ninject MVC3 is never executed.

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(NGC.web.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "Start")] is ignored it seems, so maybe WebActivator is the problem?

Comment: I solved the issue by changeing the setup method, as described here:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Problem sometimes is related with the fact that you cannot debug strartup code in an Azure web role. That code was executing so early inside the runtime that Visual Studio debugger missed it. check [this](http://www.heikura.info/debugging-application-start-c) out

Answer (score 1):

As @Igorek pointed out, make sure you're shipping the Ninject DLLs along with your project.

To accomplish this, look at the properties of the Ninject.DLL reference. You should have `Copy Local` set to `true`. If you don't do this, the Ninject DLL won't be part of your deployment in your Windows Azure Role instances.

[image: DLL copy-local property]

Comment: I solved the issue by changeing the setup method, as described here:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application

Thank you for the help :)